# <rich:calendar> doesn't accept java.util.Calendar

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I'm trying to use `rich:calendar` and it works when date properties `selectedDate` and `currentDate` are `Date` type. When I use `Calendar`, it doesn't work.

When I submit a form, it reports:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/PORTAL] threw exception [javax.el.ELException: /test.xhtml @58,36 value="#{bean.calendar.selectedDate}": Cannot convert 24.6.11 0:00 of type class java.util.Date to class java.util.Calendar] with root cause
javax.el.ELException: /test.xhtml @58,36 value="#{bean.calendar.selectedDate}": Cannot convert 24.6.11 0:00 of type class java.util.Date to class java.util.Calendar
```

**My XHTML**:

```
<rich:calendar 
  mode="ajax" id="calendar"
  value="#{bean.calendar.selectedDate}"  
  locale="#{calendarBean.locale}"  
  datePattern="#{calendarBean.pattern}"                        
  required="true">                   
</rich:calendar>
```

**And calendar bean**:

```
@ManagedBean
public class CalendarBean
{    
  private Calendar currentDate;  
  private Calendar selectedDate;

  public Calendar getCurrentDate() {  
    return currentDate;  
  }  
  public void setCurrentDate(Calendar currentDate) {  
    this.currentDate = currentDate;  
  } 
  public Calendar getSelectedDate() { 
    return selectedDate;  
  }  
  public void setSelectedDate(Calendar selectedDate) {  
    this.selectedDate = selectedDate;  
  }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @mre: this makes no sense. In locales where a Gregorian calendar is been used, the `Calendar` is a `GregorianCalendar` **already**. Look again, `Calendar` is an interface. You can find the concrete implementation of your `Calendar` class by `System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getClass())`. All other implementations should not behave differently.

Comment: @BalusC, hm..I think I get what you're saying. I suggested `GregorianCalendar` since it's a class, rather than an interface. I'll remove my suggestion though if it's incorrect. :)

Comment: @mre: Study a bit more about interfaces and polymorphism. Play around with JDBC and different DB's for a while until you finally realize the power of interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class has a `time` property which represents a [`java.util.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), complete with a [getter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime%28%29) and [setter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTime%28java.util.Date%29). Make use of it.

```
value="#{bean.calendar.selectedDate.time}"
```

Comment: Thanks, but now: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /test.xhtml @58,36 value="#{bean.calendar.selectedDate.time}": Target Unreachable, 'selectedDate' returned null ......?

Comment: You need to make sure that it is not null. Instantiate it in `CalendarBean`'s constructor. E.g. `this.selectedDate = Calendar.getInstance();` and on.

Comment: Thank you, BalusC, when I finish the school, I'll send you a title :)

Comment: your answer saved me @BalusC